# Reading Encrypted data with Datastage Tool

Tags: mysql, sql, database, etl, datastage

Actually i need Your help in datastage 11.7 tool. i am reading a AES encrypted column from my source and type of column is **nvarchar** so when we start our job and read data from source. The job run Successfully and exactly same data is moved to my target data base with same column type.

And the Problem Actually occur is that when i query the data to check whether the my source and target values are same, the query does not show any result and visually if we look source,target value they are same value but sql statement return nothing and the database is Vertica.
Column value are special Alpha numeric and special characters like `�D�&7��x��d$�Q`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure this is even properly possible via datastage - treated encrypted data and a varchar. Some DB's have internal keys that go with the data that require decrypting before extracting. I'm assuming that decrypting, transporting, landing and then encrypting is not an option.

But if I had to take a stab in the dark.

The very first thing I'd check is that the character set and collation is the same on both databases on a table level. A difference can result in blank results on the target side.

Also check that the NLS map in the datastage (map for stages and collation locale) is set accordingly. What that settings is, I don't know but making it the same in DataSTage and the DBs would be ideal ; Google. You need to comment on what is already set in the DB's. And run tests. I'm not sure the DataStage default of ISO-8859-1 will work.

Please post your solution if you find one.

Comment: YEAH I have check the character set of my source and target, there is difference between source and target. My source does not have UTF8 but after passing data through datastage the data is converted to UTF8 which is not allowing to match

Comment: and please guide me about that how can i check character set of source database vertica?

Comment: To clarify: I assumed your source was MySQL and your target Vertica based on your ticket details (i.e. MySQL tag and mentioning Vertica). But is your source Vertica as well? So it's Vertica source and target? What is the source and target character sets at the moment? And what is it set to in DataStage?

Comment: YES my source and target databases are Vertica and their column data type is Varchar and in datastage job my column data type is also varchar with UNICODE extended. When i run my job exactly same data is copied to my target but When i query the data source,target with SQL EQUAL condition, the query does not show any result.